# Upgrade or install Utility `stat`

Tags: bash

I tried to install GNU utility `stat`

```
    $ brew install stat
    Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

However,it succeeded to install GNU Bash

How to achieve such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stat is part of the coreutils package.

```
brew install coreutils
```

This installs stat with a g prefix: `gstat`.

You can avoid the g prefix by following the Caveats section:

> All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'.
>
> If you really need to use these commands with their normal names, you
>   can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
>
> ```
> PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
> ```